# VB.NET program generates false email size limit error

Tags: vb.net, exchange-server, system.net.mail

I have a VB.NET program which sends 4 attachments to 5 external recipients daily. Every day these attachments are the same size, ranging from 149KB to 161KB.

Some days, the message gets bounced back from our exchange server with this message:

> Remote Server returned '550 5.2.3 RESOLVER.RST.SendSizeLimit.Org;
>   message too large for this organization'

The size of the message should be approximately 160*4=640KB, but the bounceback tells us:

> This message wasn't delivered to anyone because it's too large. The
>   limit is 24 MB. This message is 35 MB.

We are not sure, but it seems like the 35 MB figure is multiplying the total size of the attachments by all 5 recipients.

Other days it sends fine. There is no pattern we can find as to when it fails - usually 1-3 days out of 5 per week. Additionally, if I send the same attachments to the same recipients using blat and a batch file, they always send correctly.

We previously ran this program on another server (now defunct) and it never failed with this message. It seems like there is something specific to this server that is interfering with the way the email sends, but we are not sure where to look. Could it be the .NET program and blat interacting somehow? I don't believe the old server had blat installed.

I personally don't have access to all the exchange logs but I had a coworker check them and they said they couldn't find anything unusual.

Edited for code:

```
Public Sub SendEmail()
        Dim objMail As New SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MailServer").ToString, 25)
        Dim objMess As MailMessage
        Dim strBody As String
        Dim JHPath As String : JHPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("JHFiles").ToString

        Try
            'create a new message object
            objMess = New Net.Mail.MailMessage()
            objMail.Timeout = 90000 '90 seconds
            'add sender to the message object
            objMess.From = New MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MailFromAddr"), "<redacted>")

            'add recipients
            For Each addr As String In ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MailToAddr").Split(";")
                objMess.To.Add(addr)
            Next

            'the body text of the email
            strBody = ""
            'add subject to the message object
            objMess.Subject = "<redacted> " & labelsDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") & " - " & <redacted>
            'add body to the message object
            objMess.Body = strBody

            Dim filAge As Integer
            'attach the 4 files necessary for the <redacted> - only today's
            For Each fil As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(JHPath)
                filAge = (Today() - IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(fil)).Days
                If filAge < 1 And Not (fil Like "*Thumbs.db") Then 'add today's files only, in case archiving did not happen
                    objMess.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(fil))
                End If
            Next


            'send the email
            Console.WriteLine(Now() & " -- Sending email.....  " & vbCrLf)
            writer.WriteLine(Now() & vbTab & "Sending email.....  " & vbCrLf)

            'try sending the message
            Try
                objMail.Send(objMess)
                writer.WriteLine(Now() & vbTab & "Email sent and cleaned up.  " & vbCrLf)
            Catch ex As Exception
                Dim mess As String : mess = Now() & " -- Failure sending email to <redacted>!"
                Console.WriteLine(mess)
                writer.WriteLine(mess)
            Finally
                'get rid of the message object, cleanup
                objMess.Dispose()
            End Try


        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(Now() & " -- Other Error Emailing to <redacted>:  " & ex.Message)
            writer.WriteLine(Now() & vbTab & "Exception while Emailing <redacted>:  " & ex.Message & vbCrLf)
            SendEmails("Error emailing <redacted>." & ex.Message & vbCrLf & ex.StackTrace)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Without showing your code there's not much we can do (remember to strip the code from any passwords and personal information before you post it).

Answer (score 0):

> We are not sure, but it seems like the 35 MB figure is multiplying the
>   total size of the attachments by all 5 recipients.

It's not totaled, it's per recipient.

I received bounced backs in exchange before like that and I was always sending over the limit that was set for the organization. Perhaps it really is over 24MB limit, even though you think it's not.

Before you go down a long painful debugging process, check all the receive and send connector size (you'll need help from you co-worker again to run the commands)

Follow this resource for the commands: 
https://flamingkeys.com/2011/04/how-to-standardise-exchange-2010-message-size-limits/

Comment: They checked the sizes for the connector and they are 24MB. How could the message be over the limit without me knowing? What could it be adding and how would I find this?

Comment: Those are questions that can't be answered, without anyone seeing the emails that are generated. Can you send yourself a local copy of the emails as well as your recipients.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by sending a local copy? If I send them, they have to go through the Exchange server.  As I mentioned in the initial post, we do receive the emails some days and they look as expected with the correct size attachments and headers look fine.

Comment: Since you're the coder? You do have the ability to connect to a different SMTP server and send them locally to your account outside of exchange to verify they are not going over 24 MB, you can also have the exchange admin temporarily increase the the allowed file size to be 50 MB and send a copy your exchange email address as well as the 5 other people. This way you can verify the file sizes as well.

Comment: We are still not sure why this happened, but it just stopped one day. Very puzzling. Thanks for everyone's responses.